# JavaScript Function gives value correct inside but returns undefined/null

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, return, undefined

Today I am amazed that a function giving correct value inside the function, but when I tried to return the same it gives undefined or null value. I don't know why. Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Javascript function code. You can see the same on JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tn8e1tpr/5/

```
function GetAddress(lat,lng)
            {
                var ret_addr='';
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[1]) {
                            //$('#origin_add').attr('value', results[1].formatted_address);
                            ret_addr=results[1].formatted_address;
                            origin_address=ret_addr;
                            $('#origin_add').attr('value', origin_address);
                            return origin_address;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `geocoder.geocode` is asynchronous, you can't just return from it, see the duplicate for solutions!

Comment: I can understand that this is a duplicate question. but if someone doesn't know either it works asynchronously or synchronously, what he will do.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate of your code, but it is an exact duplicate of the issue. The other question shows you the difference and how to work with asynchronous code, which is what you need to learn, and your issue is that you're trying to return from asynchronous code, but that can't be done, you have to work around it with callbacks, promises or whatever you choose, just not returns.